# How to search for an ID and its descendants in this query?

Tags: oracle, query, optimization, performance, query-performance

I have the following tables:

```
Project                Unit         
-------------          ---------------
ID  | IDUnit           ID   | IdParent
```

I have to select all projects that have the IDUnit equal to `X` and all its descendants.

I am doing the following:

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM Project p
WHERE 
(

  P_Id    IS NULL

  OR (
    p.IDUnit IN (SELECT ID FROM Unit
    START WITH ID =   P_Id
    CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = IdParent)
  )
)
```

It works, but the table `Unit` has too many rows, and the query takes over 5 seconds to complete when there is value on `P_Id`.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: Have you had any joy with this?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
select id, idunit
from (select id as idunit from unit start with id=p_id connect by prior id = idparent)
     join project using(idunit)
where p_id is not null
union all
select id, idunit from project where p_id is null
```

Comment: Eliminating `OR` conditions often helps, but in this case I'm not sure it will.  Without a comment from the OP we won't know.  Just to be picky I could also point out that this solution would need to be modified to return the same columns as the OP's.

Comment: Yes, I don't know if it would help either. Isn't `p.*` the same as `id, idunit`?

Comment: I assumed he wasn't showing all the columns.  You may be right.

Comment: I see what you mean - I guess he isn't but I suppose it is still ok to assume that he is in the context of the information given and let the OP translate back to his real-world case